# When accounts are merged, are hats also?

Tags: support, merge-accounts, winter-bash-2014

If accounts get merged during WinterBash, do hats get transferred as well?

Just curious.

Comment: Admit it: You want a Kofia hat on a site on which you have already posted.

Comment: Since hats are not stored in the same database I'd say "no, hats are not being merged" but if the hat-awarding script is checking backwards then it might simply re-award all the hats from scratch.

Comment: If they're anything like badges, then no. When accounts get merged, the badges all get cleared and then re-awarded based upon what is still eligible for a badge.

Comment: You are aware that sqlserver supports cross-db inserts and selects @ShadowWizard

Comment: @rene yeah, but is coding such thing trivial?

Comment: @ShadowWizard well, give me a minute ;)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Well, don't we all?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289059/245360) the answer is no.

The hats are awarded based on the account ID, so the hats of either of those accounts will be your new hats.

Comment: That isn't what that answer says. It only states that *The choice of which version of "Where in the world" gets awarded is based on the account Id.* it makes no other assertion about accountId. Indeed it mentions that in general with merges one account "gains stuff" from the other though stops short of explicitly stating whether or not this happens with hats.

Comment: How the version of Where in the World? is awarded is special. Other hats aren't keyed to account ID in that way. If they're keyed to account ID, it's for reasons entirely separate — therefore may or may not be, regardless of how Where in the World? works.