# Would it have been possible to get both versions of "Where in the World" with an account-merger?

Tags: support, merge-accounts, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016, secret-hats

[image: moon] [image: sun]

There are [two different versions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288457/239016) of the hat "Where in the World?", which, according to [the list of hat-triggers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/239016), is awarded

> [f]or participating on a site, when it's December 21 (the December solstice) *anywhere* in the World. (This hat comes in two forms, but you can only get one.)

What would've happened if on December 21, I had had two accounts, say one on *Stack Overflow* and one on *Super User*, using different usernames and e-mail addresses, and had gotten different versions of the hat on each, and then had requested to merge my accounts?

**Would the hats have been merged as well, giving me both versions to wear?**

Comment: If it works the same as for [badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167523/where-did-my-unsung-hero-badge-go#comment492650_167523), the answer is **no**.

Comment: Related question (which is still unanswered): [When accounts are merged, are hats also?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246231/when-accounts-are-merged-are-hats-also)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. A merge always has a direction, one account is deleted and the other gains stuff from the first.

The choice of which version of "Where in the world" gets awarded is based on the account Id.

Comment: So if the deleted account had the moon and the retained account had none but _would've gotten the sun_, after the merge it _would have_ the sun?

Comment: *based on the account Id*, you mean the highest/lowest?

Comment: based on the surviving account.

Comment: @SQB I guess that puts a related question. Is the hat type assigned at the time the hat is earned or even before that, when the account is recognised as participating in the Winter Bash? (Not that it should matter much, it's only implementation)

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code going off of other answers which state something like "the state of the hat is unknown until it is checked", it's assigned when earned. I may be wrong though.

Comment: If the deleted account has additional hats (not just a different hat variant) will these be gained by the "kept" account?

Comment: @MartinSmith [When accounts are merged, are hats also?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/246231)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - that's why I'm asking. The answer there references this one.

Comment: @MartinSmith Sure. But comments don't work for asking nor answering new questions, so asking here isn't really helpful. Maybe put a bounty on that question. :)