# If I delete and recreate an account with association bonus, will I get the Still Fresh hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

The [Still Fresh](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/still-fresh) hat has the following trigger:

> be a user on the site for less than 6 months before Winter Bash, or join during Winter Bash; have earned at least 25 reputation

Suppose I have an old account on a Stack Exchange site, so I don't qualify for this hat. Since the [association bonus counts towards the reputation requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319839/295232), can I delete and recreate the account to obtain the hat?

Comment: Considering this was a question I asked balpha when I saw the hats list... I think it's a worthy question. There are certainly a few very avid users who've gone to the trouble of creating profiles on every site and who might not otherwise have a way to achieve this hat. :)

Comment: ... but can you merge a second account to get the hat? I wonder.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara it seems to be 'no': https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289059/295232

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this works. I've deleted the Stack Overflow account of my sockpuppet:

[image]

and recreated the account a few minutes later. It now has one badge less, but it does have the Still Fresh hat:

[image]

Whether this *should* work is another matter, but it's probably (too) hard for the SQL query to take this into account.

Comment: I did exactly that with my Ethereum account, to test.

Comment: @Mithrandir ... "test"?

Comment: @Catija - Since you suggested it, I decided to test that it would actually work. I had been skeptical.

Comment: And they say the diamond makes people believe what you say... LIES! ;)

Comment: I wonder if this will work for the "Member of the Hand" hat  (+3 post as new contributor, meta or main)

Comment: Are you having a midlife crisis???  Do you want to stay young and fresh?  **:D ;-)**  **+1**