# 404 error when (re)creating account from the "account deletion completed" page

Tags: bug, deleted-accounts, 404-not-found, sign-up

When you delete one of your profiles, you end up at this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/delete/completed

[image: delete completed page]

After clicking the blue 'Join this community' button in the top bar, you'll reach the Confirm Your New Account page:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/join?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fusers%2fdelete%2fcompleted

[image: confirm new account page]

After confirming, the account was recreated but I was redirected to this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/delete/completed?newreg=91fa4b3fd00c4f8fb8b74040095b7e70
which gives a 404 Page Not Found:

[image]

It happens on more sites, not just Stack Overflow. If I join from the homepage, it works fine.

Comment: Well.. I consider this as one of those "Nobody should be doing this for any logical reason" bugs. Why would anyone want to join the site right after deleting their account on it?

Comment: Someone made up their mind? Somebody wants to [test a Winter Bash corner case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320406/295232)?

Comment: And there might be other pages where this problem occurs, though I've tried joining from a few other non-obvious pages and there it worked without 404s. Still, the setup of this page which causes the bug might be used on other pages as well; I hope the devs can find out.

Comment: Looks like it redirects you back to the page you were at before registering, `/users/delete/completed`, which shows a 404 error page unless it was accessed immediately after removing an account. After registering, that same page is reloaded, resulting in the 404 error you see. You get the same behavior if you register from any page that doesn't exist for anyone.