# How to get Miranda hat if you can't suggest edits anymore

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

I've got the edit privilege and I can't suggest edits anymore.

Do I have to suggest edits on another Stack Exchange site to get the Miranda hat?

Comment: You could try suggesting an edit to a tag-description.

Comment: Yeah, that's how you do it

Comment: I wonder what if someone has more than 20k rep then

Comment: Oh I mean, try an edit on a site you're a low rep user on

Comment: It's nearly impossible to get all the hats on a single site as there are many other hats that can't be earned by established accounts (such as the hats for taking the tour and asking your first question) and several that require some rep (so you can access the review queues). It might be to encourage you to try some other sites.

Comment: @Luuklag chances are that Winter Bash would end before the tag edit on Stack Overflow is reviewed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the hat by suggesting edits on tag wikis until you obtain the [Trusted User privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) at 20,000 rep.

> Trusted users are allowed to perform trusted actions, including:
>
> [ ... ]
>
> • Editing tag wikis without needing approval

You won't be able to obtain the hat if you have >20,000 rep on a particular site. You can always try to earn that hat on another site where you're able to suggest edits.

Comment: Oh, worst feeling even if I have trusted user privilege :(

Comment: @turivishal you can always lose reputation if you want :)

Comment: And if you're a CM that has mod powers on every site... You just can't earn the hat. T_T

Comment: @V2Blast can you... create a new account, get the hat there, and then request an account merge? Oh wait... [nvm?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246231/997587)