# The Tourist hat excludes users who previously had the Informed badge

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022, informed-badge

It seems unfair that users who already had the [Informed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) on a given site are entirely ineligible to earn the [Tourist hat](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/tourist) on that site during the Winter Bash 2022. This should be a season of inclusiveness, and should not exclude/penalize the *literally millions* of long-time loyal site users who've previously earned this badge and want to fully enjoy the Winter Bash.

This is a request for enhancement to remedy this problem somehow, making it possible for users who previously had the Informed badge to earn the Tourist hat *on their favorite Stack Exchange site*.

Some potential implementation ideas:

1. Adjust the Tourist hat requirements to award for simply visiting the Tour page during Winter Bash, regardless of the Informed badge.
2. Award the Tourist hat on ***all*** sites when it's earned on ***any*** site.
3. Reset the Informed badge for all users, at least for the duration of Winter Bash.
4. Deploy a new, temporary "Informed in the Bash" badge that awards for visiting the Tour page and adjust the Tourist hat to require that badge instead.

Can something like this be deployed?

Comment: Eh, not every hat has to be earnable by everyone. there's certainly a few others that are ***far*** easier to earn for some people than others for similar reasons

Comment: @KevinB This objection is not based on difficulty (or even relatively difficulty) of the task, but on the fact that it's literally *impossible* to earn this hat on a site where you already have the badge. That just seems like poor design.

Comment: It's not much different from [How to get Miranda hat if you can't suggest edits anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384841/how-to-get-miranda-hat-if-you-cant-suggest-edits-anymore); I can't earn that hat on SO, but i can earn it elsewhere.

Comment: @KevinB the argument that something else is equally broken shouldn't be a valid justification to avoid fixing any one of these design defects.

Comment: I think this is a valid request. Someone who has a profile on every site (not uncommon because of groups like Charcoal) and has read the tour everywhere in the past (or scripted it, not knowing it would affect them years down the line) is now totally ineligible to earn the hat at all. Same goes for someone who doesn't wish to create a profile on a site just to earn the hat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a minimum reputation to obtain hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340210/282094) https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/282094

Comment: @Rob no, not by far, it got totally nothing to do with this question. Dan, in case the question is closed (as duplicate) please ping me and I'll reopen it.

Comment: @Sha, you can see that's correct; it's tagged by design long before your comment.

Comment: Ok, if it's by design that I can't get the Tourist hat by taking the tour on a site that I've already taken the tour on, could the description at least be updated to make that clear? I was wondering why I didn't get the hat despite taking the tour on 3 of the sites that I'm on during the Bash.

Answer (score 10):

While a valid request, this is likely by design. Winter Bash hats almost always encourage [some kind of positive behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271140/what-positive-behavior-is-each-hat-encouraging) in different areas across the site.

The Tourist hat, which the name itself implies, is *likely* part of a trend of hats that encourages users to join / contribute to a *new* site. This includes this year's The Explorer hat too.

All of the following hats are unattainable if you do not join a new site.

**The Explorer, 2022**

> Ask a question that's well-received by the community on a site you haven't used before.

**Sunrise, 2021**

> Description: Write a well-received first question
> Tip: Ask a question that's well-received by the community on a site you haven't used before.

**Gimme Space, 2020**

> Join new community.
> Join a Stack Exchange community that you have never participated in.

**Mother of Dragons, 2019**

> Create a first post (question or answer) that after 3 days is +3 or higher.

**Member of The Hand 2018**

> +3 post as new contributor, meta or main

<sup>Furthermore, there's some leeway – in the event that you haven't read the Tour yet on a site you joined a site in the past, you're still able to get the hat without joining a new site.</sup>

*<sup>However, this hat gets slightly more difficult for users who have profiles across the entire Stack Exchange network. In that case, the only way to get the hat is to delete one of the profiles (of course, one that has less to no activity) and re-create it if one **must** get that hat.</sup>*

Comment: The Tourist hat could be modified to encourage joining new sites while still rewarding users by granting them a hat on their favorite site. Specifically, if the idea is to reward the USER (as opposed to the profile), then I see no fundamental reason the hat must be rewarded only on the site profile the user recently created. I've added this suggestion to the original post as idea number 2.